# python django challenge app and while passing url which contains numeric produce below error

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseNotFound

# Create your views here.
def index(request,week):
    return HTTPResponse(week)

def allweek(request,week):
    text=None
    if week=='sunday':
        text='Sunday is funday and also utilize well'
    elif week=='monday':
        text='start of week and after break'
    elif week=='tuesday':
        text='very long meetings'
    elif week=='wednesday':
        text='finished half of week'
    elif week=='thursday':
        text='preparing for weekend party day'
    elif week=='friday':
        text='weekend arrived'
    elif week=='saturday':
        text='wait is over enjoy tour day!'
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Entered wrong week of the day')
    return HttpResponse(text)


urls.py

    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('<int:week>',views.index),
        path('<str:week>',views.allweek),
        
    ]
```

Getting below error while executing the above code
As i tried to use int and str values in the urls to map the respective views but while mapping the int values below error is encountered.

AttributeError at /challenges/1
'int' object has no attribute 'makefile'

while runni

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your `urls` you are calling `index` view function. And you are returning http client `HTTPResponse`. The `HTTPResponse` class instance are returned after successful connection and are not instantiated directly by user.

So change your index `views.py` from

```
def index(request,week):
    return HTTPResponse(week)
```

To this

```
def index(request,week):
    return HttpResponse(week)
```